# How to start Realm object server with custom authentication

Tags: javascript, realm, realm-object-server

I have updated index.js file with custom authentication based on 
https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/index.html#custom-authentication

Below is the content of my index.js file

```
const RealmObjectServer = require('realm-object-server');
const path = require('path');
const Realm = require('realm');
const server = new RealmObjectServer.BasicServer();

// Update the default path where Realm will be stored.
Realm.defaultPath = './data/realms/MyCustomRealm.realm'

class MyAuthProvider extends RealmObjectServer.auth.AuthProvider {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = 'myAuthProvider';
        console.log("Realm default Path = " + Realm.defaultPath)
    }

    authenticateOrCreateUser(body) {
        console.log("In authenticateOrCreateUser with body = ", body)
        const userId = body.userId;
        return this.service.createOrUpdateUser(
                                               userId,
                                               "myAuthProvider",
                                               false,
                                               null
                                               );
    }
}

server.start({
             dataPath: path.join(__dirname, '../data'),
             authProviders: [ new MyAuthProvider() ],
             }).catch((err) => {
                      console.error("There was an error starting your custom ROS Server", err);
                      });
```

How do I start the server so that my "authenticateOrCreateUser" method is called?

I tried doing following:

```
ros start --auth myAuthProvider
ros start --auth MyAuthProvider
```

but got following errors:

```
The auth provider 'myAuthProvider' cannot be found or does not have a default export
The auth provider 'MyAuthProvider' cannot be found or does not have a default export
```

I am new to javascript so not sure what default export is and how can it be added?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the server with

npm start

from your app directory.